# Why is vectorized numpy code slower than for loops?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have two numpy arrays, `X` and `Y`, with shapes `(n,d)` and `(m,d)`, respectively. Assume that we want to compute the Euclidean distances between each row of `X` and each row of `Y` and store the result in array `Z` with shape `(n,m)`. I have two implementations for this. The first implementation uses two for loops as follows:

```
for i in range(n):
      for j in range(m):
        Z[i,j] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(X[i] - Y[j])))
```

The second implementation uses only one loop by vectorization:

```
for i in range(n):
      Z[i] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(X[i]-Y), axis=1))
```

When I run these codes on a particular `X` and `Y` data, the first implementation takes nearly 30 seconds while the second implementation takes nearly 60 seconds. I expect the second implementation to be faster since it uses vectorization. What is the reason of its slow running? I know that we can obtain faster implementations by fully vectorizing the code, but I don't understand why the second code (which is partially vectorized) is slower than non-vectorized version.

Here is the complete code:

```
n,m,d = 5000,500,3000
X = np.random.rand(n,d)
Y = np.random.rand(m,d)
Z = np.zeros((n,m))

tic = time.time()
for i in range(n):
      for j in range(m):
        Z[i,j] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(X[i] - Y[j])))
print('Elapsed time 1: ', time.time()-tic)

tic = time.time()
for i in range(n):
      Z[i] = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(X[i]-Y), axis=1))
print('Elapsed time 2: ', time.time()-tic)


tic = time.time()
train_squared = np.square(X).sum(axis=1).reshape((1,n))
test_squared = np.square(Y).sum(axis=1).reshape((m,1))
test_train = -2*np.matmul(Y, X.T)
dists = np.sqrt(test_train + train_squared + test_squared)
print('Elapsed time 3: ', time.time()-tic)
```

And this is the output:

```
Elapsed time 1:  35.659096002578735
Elapsed time 2:  65.57051086425781
Elapsed time 3:  0.3912069797515869
```

Comment: What are the typical values of `n,m,d` in your testing?

Comment: @Divakar `n=5000, m=500, d=3000`

Comment: For me, first took 24 sec, second 20 sec. Share your benchmarking setup?

Comment: @Divakar Even with the random data, I get the same result. I updated the question to include the complete code and outputs.

Comment: Vectorization doesn't always pay off if you have to take a large memory usage increase to do it. You start running out of cache and stuff like that.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks. So what is the increased memory usage in my implementation? By the way, the fully vectorized version of this code is really fast (lower than 1 second) although it presumably takes much larger memory usage.

Comment: @Hossein: The first version uses temporary arrays of shape `(d,)`; the second version uses temporaries of shape `(m, d)`, much bigger. I don't know what your fully vectorized solution looks like, so I don't know what size of temporaries that's producing.

Comment: By the way, I don't know if you know this, but SciPy comes with [a function to do what you're trying to do](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html).

Comment: It really shouldn't be a memory issue with that small a dataset.  A `3000x5000` array full of `float64's` (which is about the biggest way you can slice it, `X-Y[i]` which he doesn't do) is only about 120MB I think.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks again. I added the full vectorized version to the question.

Comment: You should use `time.clock` instead of `time.time`. Otherwise any other programs which keeptl the CPU busy are part of your benchmark results.

Comment: @Hossein For this kind of performance question it is very helpful to include the version of Python you are using and the versions of all involved libraries (`numpy` in this case). Also information about the operating system and the hardware which you are using can be essential. I just tested your example with Python 2 and 3 and both the 1st and 2nd case used roughly the same amount of time (a few seconds difference).

Comment: @a_guest My python and numpy versions are 3.5.3 and 1.12.1, respectively. I use the macOS Sierra with 2.6 GHz Core i5 processor and 8 GB Ram.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I pulled apart your equations and reduced it down to this [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        Y[j].copy()

for i in range(n):
    Y.copy()
```

The `copy()` here is just to simulate the subtraction from `X`.  The subtraction itself should be quite cheap.

Here's the results on my computer:

- The first one took 10ms.
- The second one took 13s!

I'm copying the exact same amount of data.  Using your choices `n=5000, m=500, d=3000`, this code is copying **60 gigabytes** of data.

To be honest, I'm not surprised at all that 13 seconds.  That's already over 4GB/s, essentially the maximum bandwidth between my CPU and RAM (of e.g. `memcpy`).

The really surprising thing is that the first test managed to copy 60GB in only 0.01seconds, which translates to 6TB/s!

I'm pretty sure this is because the data isn't actually leaving the CPU at all.  It's just bouncing back and forth between the CPU and the L1 cache: an array of 3000 double-precision numbers will easily fit in a 32KiB L1 cache.

Therefore, I deduce that the main reason your second algorithm isn't as great as one would naively expect is because processing a whole chunk of `500×3000` elements per iteration is very unfriendly to the CPU cache: you basically evict the whole cache into RAM!  In contrast, your first algorithm is does take advantage of cache to some extent, because the `3000` elements will still be in cache by the time the `sum` gets computed, so there's not nearly as much data moving between your CPU and RAM.  (Once you have the sum, the `3000` element array is "thrown away", which means it will probably just get overwritten in cache and never make it back to the actually RAM.)

---

Naturally, doing matrix multiplication is insanely faster, because your problem is essentially of the form:

```
C[i, j] = ∑[k] f(A[i, k], B[j, k])
```

If you replace `f(x, y)` with `x * y`, you can see it's just a variant of matrix multiplication.  The operation `f` is not extremely important here − what is important are how the indices behave in this equation, which determines how your arrays are stored in memory.  The essence of matrix multiplication algorithms lies in the ability to cope with this kind of array access through *blocking*, so in principle the overall algorithm does not change dramatically even for a user-defined `f`.  Unfortunately, in *practice* there are very few libraries that support user-defined operations, so you have use the trick `(X - Y)**2 = X**2 - 2 X Y + Y**2` as you have done.  But it gets the job done :D

Comment: Could you please share how you benchmarked that code? While your argument, that the result of the subtraction remains in the CPU cache and that it can be reused for the sum without using the memory bus, may apply to the case of the OP, I don't see how this plays a role for your `copy()` example. For the first approach (double `for`-loop) you copy a different row for each inner iteration `j`, so this needs to be copied from the RAM. I doubt that the Python compiler swaps the inner and outer loop (while gcc probably would). I ran your example and it was roughly the same time for both cases.

Comment: I used the same benchmarking functions as the OP. It was done on Arch Linux with Python 3. My guess is that how much it reuses the small buffer is probably highly dependent on the system allocator, which is probably why there is a huge variation in results.

Comment: Okay, so I checked it: `Y[j].copy().__array_interface__["data"]` gives me the same pointer every single time, so the allocator is indeed reusing the same buffer.

Comment: @Rufflewind: while I understand the reasoning about the cache size etc, I do not think this explains whats happening. numpy vectorization is only meant to move the loops from python deeper to the C implementation; they're still there and vectorization does not really remove them only pushes them deeper. Otherwise there will almost never be a benefit to vectorization.

Comment: @Kai I'm confused.  I did not mention anything about removal of loops.  What I explained is that when loops traverse over the same piece of memory repeatedly, it stays hot in cache and reduces unnecessary movement between the memory hierarchies.

Comment: Im saying that the for loops are still the same, except that with vectorization they're moved to the underlying C implementation. So in terms of "cache hotness" both vectorized and vanilla should be the same. it may be the case that the way vectorization is implemented, it will cause a lot of cache thrashing when arrays are large; which means that vectorization should only be used for small-ish arrays. I would hesitate to take this stance though without knowing what's going on first.

Comment: There's no mystery to Numpy's behavior: it takes an input array, allocates a fresh output array from scratch, and then processes each element. The result is that there's going to be a data movement equal to the size of array. If the output buffer gets deallocated and reallocated with the same size, it gets reused (due to a fortuitous quirk in allocator), which means the array stays in cache so the movement is much faster than if it had to be sent all the way to and from RAM for an array that is too large for cache.

Comment: @Rufflewind, so you're saying numpy vectorization slows things down when arrays exceed some limit related to cache size? doing all computation you need while data is still in cache is a known strategy, its not new; we called strip-mining earlier in my career. I don't think numpy designers would miss that. I also don't see anything in the docs that says avoid vectorization for large arrays. I would say there's more to it. By the way, I recreated the O.P experiment and got the same results: 18 s for two for loops, 65 s single for loop and 180 s fully vectorized (without linear algebra trick)

Comment: @Kai Numpy has an eagerly-evaluated API: nearly every Numpy operation returns array with all the items computed and stored in memory. This means the cost of any operation, at minimum, requires storing all the output in memory. The one-loop code forces Numpy to dump all `500×3000` to memory (too large for cache), whereas the two-loop code only dumps out `3000` to memory (fits in cache). This is a fundamental limitation of Numpy's API and no amount of optimization can resolve that. The only way to avoid this would be to use some kind of lazily-evaluated array, but that's not `ndarray` anymore.